# How can I `alias sudo !!`?

Tags: bash, sudo, alias, command-history, history-expansion

I'm trying to set an alias for `sudo !!` in Bash. I tried `alias sbb='sudo !!`', but it interprets that as a literal  `!!` and prints

```
sudo: !!: command not found
```

If I use double quotes, it substitutes the double bang in the string itself, so that doesn't work.

Is there any way to make this work? Or an alternative alias?
`

Comment: See also [Execute a line of commands with one sudo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138276/execute-a-line-of-commands-with-one-sudo)

Comment: Possible same on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/240180/creating-an-alias-containing-bash-history-expansion

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`!!` is expanded by bash when you type it. It's not expanded by alias substitution.

You can use the `history` built-in to do the expansion:

```
alias sbb='sudo $(history -p !!)'
```

If the command is more than a simple command (e.g. it contains redirections or pipes), you need to invoke a shell under sudo:

```
alias sbb='sudo "$BASH" -c "$(history -p !!)"'
```

Comment: Got one for tcsh?

Comment: @mdpc: I don't use tcsh, but I glanced at `man tcsh` and discovered that it *does* do history expansion during alias expansion "as though the original command were the previous input line." Interesting. However, `alias sbb 'sudo \!-2` did not work as expected (it actually substituted the second previous entry); `alias sbb 'sudo \!\!'` did work as expected (substituted `sbb` for `!!`); and in the end it turned out that what I wanted was `alias sbb 'sudo \!-1'` which I would have expected to be the same as `\!\!`. (tcsh 6.17.06 (Astron) 2011-04-15) YMMV. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  This alias is great when as administrator you forget to put sudo in front of your command.

Comment: instead of `sbb` I would prefer `prease` as alias as suggested by @jpschorr

Comment: `usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
`

Answer (score 53):

Try:

```
alias sbb='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
```

I like actually prefer to name it 'please':

```
alias please='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'
```

Info: *[`fc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) is a in-built command in the bash shell. that lists, edits and reexecutes commands previously entered to an interactive shell.*

Zsh has the similar issue with `!!` and aliases, and `fc -ln -1` also works there. Though caveats about getting redirections and other shell syntax inside the sudo'ed command line apply, so you may want to wrap the command within a shell invocation or `eval`, see [@rici's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85354/170373).

Comment: `please` is definitely the way to go !

Comment: works for bash too so removed the 'for zsh' comment.

Comment: Works well in zsh. fc is the command to use. Thanks

Comment: `please` makes it feel like the terminal is an entity that I have to *be nice to* in order to get stuff done. I prefer something that gives a better sense of control - like `fuck` ;)

Comment: `pls`, because `please` but also I'm salty

Comment: Is this functionally equivalent to Giles 2nd version? I'm not sure if they'll both work or if there might be slight differences.

Answer (score 6):

Now there's a repository for this purpose in GitHub, it magically checks whether it needs superuser rights, also fixes the typos:

https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck

Comment: I tried `apt-get install thefuck` which exists, but it [doesn't work](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/issues/516) on my Ubuntu 15.10 ;(

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that for `zsh` if you share history between multiple shell instances ([SHARE_HISTORY](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) option), you really want to restrict fc lookup to the instance you're currently using. Otherwise, you'll get all of the commands issued since *your shell's* last one, joined together on a single line.

```bash
alias please='sudo $(fc -Lln -1)'
```

Answer (score -1):

<sup>This was originally posted at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252959/66803) question but later, suggested to post here.</sup>

Here is how you can use `fc` and `history` with alias for `!-` like substitutions. Suppose if you want to use `!-n` (where **n** is digit for n<sup>th</sup> last command used), then you can use `fc` and `history` with alias as follows:

1. Using **`history`**:

   ```
   alias xyz='echo $(history -p "!-<n>") ; sudo $(history -p "!-n")'
   ```

   Note: Here `!-n` should be enclosed with `'` or `''`.
2. Using **`fc`**:

   ```
   alias xyz='echo $(fc -ln -n -n) ; sudo $(fc -ln -n -n)'
   ```

   Note: here 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> `-n` are used to specify the range of history list.

Here I used echo-ing before executing command for felling like `!-<n>`.

Comment: Previous answers already cover `history -p` and `fc`. Anything new here?

Comment: Ok, What of it?

Comment: I find the `-ln -n -n` to be intensely confusing; also the bit about `'` or `''` (and also the bit about `-<n>`).

Comment: Option 2. must be a typo, I think you want `$(fc -ln -1)`

Answer (score -3):

```
alias please="sudo $(history -p \!\-2)"
```