# Execute a line of commands with one sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, command-history

For example if I want to create a file and enter text in one line I can redirect the output into a file with the use of the `>` operator:

```
echo "something" > /path/foobar
```

but if I don't have access to the folder `/path/` and need sudo priviledges, How can I achieve this same command as a normal user with sudo rights?

I tried

```
sudo echo "something" > /path/foobar
```

but that doesn't work, because the sudo only counts for the `edit` but not for the right part
of the `>`

Sure, I could become root before with `sudo su` or use `tee` instead:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee /path/foobar
```

But I would like to find a solution where I can work with the last line as replacement via

```
sudo !!
```

Isn't there a way to "recycle" the last line and just add `sudo` in front?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I extracted the real Qeustion and changed the title. Now it is what I am really looking for

Comment: It certainly *was* a duplicate, but it is somewhat different now. It looks to me like you rewrote the question in light of Boogy's answer, which is fine -- that is a good answer.  I've retracted my close vote, but it is still inevitable (people often vote automatically once a question is in the close queue without paying attention to the issue): address a comment @goldilocks when it gets closed and I'll vote to reopen.  You can also plead your case in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) once that happens.

Comment: See also [How can I `alias sudo !!`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85352/how-can-i-alias-sudo)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't just stick `sudo` in front of a shell command, you have to invoke a shell to evaluate that command again (doing things like expanding variables, opening files for redirection operators, etc.). So that's

```
sudo bash -c !!
```

except that this doesn't quite work, because `!!` interpolates the text of the previous command, special characters and all. You need to retrieve the text of the command as a string and pass that as an argument to `sh`. Fortunately, bash's [`fc` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-fc) lets you do that¹.

```
sudo bash -c "$(fc -ln -1)"
```

Or even, to be sure to invoke the same version of bash that's currently running:

```
sudo "$BASH" -c "$(fc -ln -1)"
```

Note that since the command is executed in a separate shell process, it inherits environment variables (only the ones that `sudo` preserves, mind), but not shell internal variables. Shell options (e.g. `kshglob`) and other settings will start from the default either.

The same command² works in zsh and ksh, though ATT ksh93 requires both the `first` and `last` number to be passed to `fc`³ (which also works in bash, zsh and pdksh/mksh):

```
sudo zsh -c "$(fc -ln -1)"
sudo ksh -c "$(fc -ln -1 -1)"
sudo "$0" -c "$(fc -ln -1 -1)"
```

Using `$0` to designate the executable of the running shell works only if the shell was invoked through the $PATH and the $PATH hasn't changed, or through an absolute path.

Here's another method in zsh which is slightly clearer but longer:

```
sudo zsh -c $history[$[HISTCMD-1]]
```

A final word of warning: `sudo` is for potentially dangerous commands. Don't make it too easy to use it!

¹  <sub>There's some extra whitespace at the beginning and the command substitution strips off newlines at the end, but the syntax of the shell doesn't care about that.</sub> 
²  <sub>I don't think zsh or ksh have anything like bash's `$BASH`; `$0` only works when it's an absolute path, or when it contains no slash and the command search path hasn't changed.</sub> 
³  <sub>`fc` is an alias for `hist` in ATT ksh but that's just as good.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

If you want to redo the same command with **sudo !!** after doing a command like this:

```
echo "something">/path/file
```

The you use the global replace syntax to recall the command :

```
!!:gs/>/|sudo tee -a /
```

*Use a space after the **-a** parameter.*

This is the equivalent to **sudo !!** but helps you bypass sudo restrictions for the < and >. Because sudo does not allow you to use [<, >].

---

To bypass sudo restrictions in general for redirections you can use it like this:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee myfile
```

tee command will allow you to read from standard input and write to standard output and files

If you want to repeat the command and append a text to the file, the tee command has the **-a** option for appending. So you could recall the command with

```
sudo !!
```

and the text will be appended in the file

example:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee -a /path/file
sudo !!
```

Comment: nice solution, but a bit hard to memorize. How can I create an [alias for a command using !! to recall the last command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138289)?

Comment: is the `-a` really needed? `>` will overwrite a file, `tee -a` will append, which would be `>>`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be as simple as `sudo sh -c "!!"`:

```
$ cd /
$ echo hello > foo
bash: foo: Permission denied
$ sudo sh -c "!!"
sudo sh -c "echo hello > foo"
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Jun 20 16:21 foo
```

Comment: If the command used quotes, this isn't necessarily equivalent. Consider `echo "foo bar"` which would become `sh -c "echo "foo bar""` which would just print `foo` instead of `foo bar`.

Comment: I tried `sudo sh -c '!!'` instead if your command but that doesn't work either

Comment: Then what if your command used both single and double quotes?  Or double quotes and variable expansions?  If the user did: `a=b` and then `echo "$a" >file` and then `sudo sh -c '!!'` it would expand to `sudo sh -c 'echo $a >file'` which would print an empty line instead of `b` into `file`.

Comment: So maybe there is an even better solution somehow?

Comment: I don't think there's any solution that will work 100% of the time without you ever needing to modify the command.  Using `sudo` to get a root shell and then copying and pasting the command into it would be closest, but fails if the command was expected to use variables that were set in your non-root shell.  Using `sudo sh -c "!!"` works fine for simple commands, but is fraught for complex ones.  I think that the best advice is to not expect that there is some command that will work 100% of the time - learn some possible solutions and apply each when it best fits.