# alias for a command using !! to recall the last command

Tags: bash, command-history, alias

This is a follow-up question to

> [Execute a line of commands with one sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138276/execute-a-line-of-commands-with-one-sudo)

If you want to redo the same command with **`sudo !!`** after doing a command like this:

```
echo "something">/path/file
```

You can use the global replace syntax to recall the command:

```
!!:gs/>/|sudo tee -a /
```

*Use a space after the **-a** parameter.*

This is the equivalent to **sudo !!** but helps you bypass sudo restrictions for the < and >. Because sudo does not allow you to use [<, >].

How can I put this into an alias on my `.bashrc` so I can use it simple?

I tried

```
alias redo='!!:gs/>/|sudo tee -a /'
```

But this doesn't work, I get the error:

```
$ echo "sdfdsf">/path/file
bash: /path/file: no permissions

$ redo
bash: /: Is a directory
tee: /: Is a directory
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the '/'? I believe \/ will work.

Comment: I tried, but no change

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
sudo sh -c "!!"
```

This will translate `!!` to your last command and keep the shell redirections/pipes/variables functional:

```
➜  ~  ping 10.0.0.1
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 3 received, 50% packet loss, time 5001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.736/1.951/2.182/0.185 ms
➜  ~  sudo sh -c "!!" ## And becomes like this:
➜  ~  sudo sh -c "ping 10.0.0.1"
```

Comment: If the command used quotes, this isn't necessarily equivalent.  Consider `echo "foo bar"` which would become `sh -c "echo "foo bar""` which would just print `foo` instead of `foo bar`.

Comment: This is perfect! but not the answer here, but to the question before: [Execute a line of commands with one sudo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138276) I see, someone was faster there, so your answer here is a duplicate of [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138302)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but: don't do this.

The idea behind this alias (assuming that it worked) is that transforming `>` into `|tee -a foo` is a good idea.  First off, even in the best of cases, they're not equivalent.  `>` will overwrite a file, `tee -a` will append.

Secondly, this doesn't handle common constructs like `echo >>foo` (which would be transformed into `echo |sudo tee -a |sudo tee -a foo` and fail) or `echo 2>&1` (which would be transformed into `echo 2|sudo tee -a &1` and fail).

Now, you may be able to write a much more complicated substitution that could handle all of these cases reasonably, but that brings me to my third point:

This would run a command as root without you having a chance to review the command that's about to be executed, which strikes me as an extremely bad idea - especially given the fact that, by the time you have something that works for even all of the most common cases it's likely going to be fairly complex.

So, all in all, I'd recommend you not attempt anything of this sort.