# Can I alias `!<editor>` in bashrc?

Tags: bash, alias, command-history

I use emacs as an editor in the command line (aliased with `alias em='emacs -nw'`) and would like to be able to make an alias for `!em` to open up the file most recently opened in emacs.

I've tried `alias e='!em'`, `alias e='${!}em'`, `alias e='${!em}'`, but so far can't find anything that works.

I've found some related posts about aliasing `!!`:

[alias for a command using !! to recall the last command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138289/alias-for-a-command-using-to-recall-the-last-command?rq=1)

Comment: This is pretty much answered in the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85352/how-can-i-alias-sudo) your linked question is marked as a duplicate of. Just use `!em` instead of `!!`.

Comment: @ilkkachu - thanks, but I tried that before I asked the question and it did not work. It does not recognize the `em` command (although they are both in `.bashrc`, and I did run `. .bashrc` of course)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think history expansion is done after expanding aliases, so you'd need to use `history -p` to do it explicitly:

```
alias e='eval "$(history -p !em)"'
```

Though that doesn't work either in this case, since aliases aren't expanded after command substitution. But functions work, so these two should do it:

```
em() { emacs -nw "$@"; }
e() { eval "$(history -p !em)"; }
```

The latter could be an alias.

Answer (score 0):

If you alias em as you described, then you should not attempt to make an additional alias for !em.  ! invokes the shell history mechanism, so the command "!em" will repeat the most recent use of your alias (which might not be the last file actually edited by emacs, however.)