# Command to 're-apply' previous command?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

Is there an easy way to re-apply a previous command to a new command line entry?

Say I typed in `chmod u+r,g+x file.txt` but forgot the sudo. Could I simply type `sudo <some easy symbol>`'?

Comment: Have you tried using your arrow keys?

Comment: Yes, looking more if I have an enter long line, or say I need to plug the previous command in between a new command.

Comment: See also [Execute a line of commands with one sudo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138276/execute-a-line-of-commands-with-one-sudo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
sudo !!
```

Another good one is `alt .`, to insert the last parameter of the previous command

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for you. Thanks.

Comment: Waiting too. Another 7 min. :)

Comment: This only works in simple cases though, not when the command is a complex one involving redirections, pipes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Press `up` arrow, press `ctrl+a`, write `sudo`, press `enter`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [basic bash shortcuts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/) you should know...

```
Ctrl + A    Go to the beginning of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + E    Go to the end of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + L    Clears the Screen.
Ctrl + U    Clears the line before the cursor position. If you are at the end of the line, clears the entire line.
Ctrl + H    Same as backspace
Ctrl + R    Let’s you search through previously used commands
Ctrl + D    Exit the current shell
Ctrl + W    Delete the word before the cursor
Ctrl + K    Clear the line after the cursor
Ctrl + T    Swap the last two characters before the cursor
Esc + T     Swap the last two words before the cursor
Alt + F     Move cursor forward one word on the current line
Alt + B     Move cursor backward one word on the current line
Tab         Auto-complete files and folder names
```

---

In your specific case, I also alias `h` to `history|grep`.

Such that:

```
# mco service sendmail status -F operatingsystemmajrelease=6
```

And I need to prepend something to that...

```
# h mco
```

Which shows...

```
  114  07-28-2014 09:33:25  mco package sendmail install -F operatingsystemmajrelease=6
  115  07-28-2014 09:33:25  mco service sendmail status -F operatingsystemmajrelease=6
  116  07-28-2014 09:33:25  mco package sendmail-cf install -F operatingsystemmajrelease=6
```

And I want line #116... So I type:

```
# !115
```

But if I need something in front of it (e.g. `sudo`), I'd do...

```
# sudo !115
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, `alt .` is an important one too. And might as well add `alt /` too, to circumvent smart tab completion and it the old fashioned way. Or `alt *`, to expand a `*`.